# could not settle on kex algorithm - SFTP connection failed

Tags: ruby, net-ssh, net-sftp

Tried to connect SFTP server using RSA private key with a ruby script. It's not connecting. But it's working using Filezilla.

Code example:

```
require 'net/sftp'

sftp = Net::SFTP.start('hostname', 'user', password: '', port: 'port', keys: '~/.ssh/private_key.pub')
sftp.connect
```

Output:

```
Failed to connect to hostname: could not settle on kex algorithm

Server kex preferences: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
Client kex preferences: ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

Using sftp command with -oKexAlgorithms argument it's working on the terminal.

```
sftp -i ~/.ssh/private_key.pub -P 16321 -oKexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -c aes128-cbc user@host
```

Comment: What server type is this?

Comment: Are you passing arguments as string? 'ftp.host' won't resolve to your host

Comment: It's an SFTP server. Passing SFTP host, username, port, and private key.